# Play Youtube Videos in Roku Channel

Tags: roku

I am new to Roku development. I want to create a Roku channel in which I want to add youtube videos, so please can anyone suggest how I can develop it on the Roku platform?

Answer (score 0):

To play videos in general, you will need to utilize the Video Node. Here is some info on the Video Node from the Roku SDK: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Video

As to adding youtube videos, it is not possible to play videos directly from youtube, unless you download the videos first using a third-party client and use that download link as the url for the Video Node.

There are some sample channels on Github for Video Players. Looking at these channels is a great way to learn, in addition to the Roku SDK. Here is one example: https://github.com/rokudev/simple-videoplayer-channel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play youtube videos directly on Roku, you have to host videos on your server or cdn depends on you. Roku can play videos of formats HLS, DASH, MP4.
Check out this link for more information https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/playing-videos.md

Answer (score -1):

You can not play youtube videos inside your  Roku application but you can launch youtube Roku channel from your app and play your content.

[Check here how to launch Youtube application from your native Roku channel](https://roku.home.blog/2018/08/28/launch-other-roku-channelnetflixyoutubeor-sling-form-your-channel-using-brighscript/)